Can I assign multiple language-dependent audio tracks to youtube video?
(similar to Does YouTube allow multiple soundtracks)
I have prepared a video that has subtitles for two different languages, and I have isolated audio-only track for these two languages, too.
The base video has no voice output.
So I wonder whether I can construct a video on youtube to have it all, sub-titles per language and audio-tracks per language.
According to How to Check If You Have YouTube's Multi-Language Audio Feature I don't have the multi-language audio feature.
My audio is all "5.1" in case it matters.

Unfortunately, this isn't currently possible. YouTube has been incredibly slow with this rollout, and it's still not available to most channels.
The best way to approach this is probably to upload two separate videos, marked with their separate languages (maybe linking to each other in the description).
Also, it seems that you're suggesting a use case where the base video has audio but no dialogue, and you want YouTube to mix in either language's dialogue? That's not the intention of their multilingual feature, you're supposed to upload entirely separate audio tracks for each language.

The original has separate audio tracks for voice comments (one per language), and all the other tracks are fed to a common bus (say "audio"). The final language audio tracks were created by mixing the "audio" bus with the specific language track, so each of the language-specific audio tracks is complete (i.e.: sound plus voice).
